# formatting date for d3.js from mysql

Tags: mysql, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a graph using google charts, and my data is stored in mysql. The columns of my data in the mysql table are "timestamp" [which stores CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ], "Side A Score" and "Side B Score".

I used php to echo the data out into a google visualization DataTable as such:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Side 0 score');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Side 1 score');
  data.addRows([
  [2014-06-15 09:40:22 , 79.5 , 20.5] , [2014-06-15 12:57:15 , 79.5 , 20.5] , [2014-06-15 12:58:48 , 79.5 , 20.5] , [2014-06-15 12:59:21 , 79.5 , 20.5] , [2014-06-15 13:00:46 , 79.5 , 20.5] , [2014-06-15 13:00:51 , 79 , 21.5] , [2014-06-15 13:02:39 , 79 , 21.5] , [2014-06-15 18:39:54 , 79 , 21.5] , [2014-06-15 18:43:01 , 78.75 , 21.25] , [2014-06-15 18:45:35 , 78.8 , 21.2] , [2014-06-15 18:46:18 , 78.8 , 21.2] , [2014-06-15 18:50:44 , 79 , 21] , [2014-06-15 18:50:52 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 18:51:02 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 18:54:02 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:03:27 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:03:38 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:04:49 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:05:07 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:05:27 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:05:55 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:06:33 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:06:57 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:07:43 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:07:45 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 19:07:52 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:23:10 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:23:16 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:23:31 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:23:53 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:24:17 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:25:21 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:27:25 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:28:03 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:28:10 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:34:55 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-15 21:35:13 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:25:53 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:26:02 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:26:08 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:26:39 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:27:36 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:57:06 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:58:00 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 21:59:14 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:00:17 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:01:44 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:03:40 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:05:04 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:07:42 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:08:17 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:09:15 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:11:47 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:12:45 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:14:13 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:17:22 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:17:31 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:19:10 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:20:10 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:20:27 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:20:51 , 79.3 , 20.7] , [2014-06-16 22:20:57 , 58.6 , 41.4] , [2014-06-16 22:32:58 , 58.6 , 41.4] , [2014-06-16 22:33:06 , 57.9 , 42.1] , [2014-06-16 22:36:06 , 58.4 , 41.6] , [2014-06-16 22:48:26 , 58.4 , 41.6] 
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'Score Chart',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width:300; height:300"></div>
```

However, it is not working and I am not seeing any visual output. I think I am making a mistake with the datetime part because google seems to require the date formatted differently. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date string should be quoted. I'm puzzled that you didn't had any errors in your console complaining for that line.

Simplest approach would be

```
data.addRows([
    ['2014-06-15 09:40:22' , 79.5 , 20.5],
    ['2014-06-15 12:57:15' , 79.5 , 20.5],
    ['2014-06-15 12:58:48' , 79.5 , 20.5],
    ['2014-06-15 12:59:21' , 79.5 , 20.5],
    ['2014-06-15 13:00:46' , 79.5 , 20.5]
]);
```

But I don't know if that graph library expects that kind of string or a Date object. So if that doesn't work, pass the string to a proper Date constructor

```
data.addRows([
    [new Date('2014-06-15 09:40:22') , 79.5 , 20.5],
    [new Date('2014-06-15 12:57:15') , 79.5 , 20.5],
    [new Date('2014-06-15 12:58:48') , 79.5 , 20.5],
    [new Date('2014-06-15 12:59:21') , 79.5 , 20.5],
    [new Date('2014-06-15 13:00:46') , 79.5 , 20.5]
]);
```

Your example is using Google Charts instead of D3, so keep in mind you'll have to adapt the syntax.

Comment: Apologies @amenadiel - you are right, I'm using Google Charts.

Comment: You should not use the Date object's string parsing - each browser parses strings differently, and even users from different regions using the same browser will get different dates.  Manually parse your dates and times into year, month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds and build a Date object from those (keeping in mind that you have to adjust months, since javascript dates index months from 0 [eg, January is 0, not 1]).

Comment: I disagree. ISO 8601 defines the standard for dateTime. It should be [YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[hh]:[mm]:[ss] but according to note 4.3.2 of the ISO 8601:2004 spec, it is ok to omit the T character.

Comment: I used the new Date method (your second para), which worked well with google's parsing method apparently. Thanks!